# About the I2C interface circuit of the Raspberry Pi Camera V2.1

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi, i2c, camera

Today, I get the [schematic of the Raspberry Pi Camera V2.1](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/camera-v2-schematics.pdf).

A snippet: [image]

The I2C interface on J1 is routed to the camera through Q1. You see, both the gate and the source are pulled up to 1V8. For SCL, the later stage is always an input with high impedance. Then what's the purpose to use a FET to **isolate** it, as the gate and source have equal level?

Edit:

I missed that the SCL is not always high impedance even for a I2C slave device, such as in Clock stretching phase. But I still open for someone to give a *complete* answer:)

A part of Q1 datasheet:

[image]

Comment: That is a common  bidirectional level shifter circuit. Works well for I2C but little else. If the source goes to 0V, mosfet turns on and pulls drain towards 0V. For the other direction, drain gets pulled to 0V, mosfet body diode conducts and source gets pulled to 0V.

Comment: Philps app note: http://cdn.sparkfun.com/tutorialimages/BD-LogicLevelConverter/an97055.pdf